# cordova exec not running

Tags: javascript, cordova, exec

I am finding that calls to exec() in Cordova are not being processed. For example, in the following, the two alert statements fire, but the exec statement does nothing, and seems to be skipped over when I trace this in Xcode.

```
alert("about to call exec in getInfo");
exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "Device", "getDeviceInfo", []);
alert("after exec in getInfo");
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Comment: what are you trying to do? exec should only be used inside a plugin to launch the associated native code, not from the app.

Comment: Indeed -- this was tracking a bug back to the line seeming to not execute

Comment: exec makes an asynchronous call to the native code of the plugin so it's normal that your 2nd alert is displayed immediatly after the first one.

The problem could come from your callbacks.